# What is background mode remote notifications for in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications, ios-background-mode

I always thought it was for push notifications but there is an option below for push notifications and lately, all apps are being rejected because they say we are using NFC which we are not using. I joined the company a few months ago and no one knows why this is enabled?

Searching for remote notifications seems to only give me unrelated answers about push notifications.

I'm using Xcode 11.5 and this option has been here for most of the Xcode 11 versions.

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Push Notifications capability enables your app to register for remote/push notifications.

If a push notification is received while your app is suspended and you have notification display permission from the user then the notification will be displayed as a banner etc.

If a push notification is received while your app is running in the foreground then the notification detail will be delivered to your app delegate.

If you have the background remote notification capability then you can send "silent" push notifications to your app that will be delivered to the app delegate even when your app isn't in the foreground. Your app can then use this opportunity to perform a small amount of processing; for example it could refresh some data or send some information to a server.

Neither of these capabilities are related to NFC